# Can you watch the attribute which triggered the directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to watch the attribute which triggered the directive?

```
export function minDirective(): ng.IDirective {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) => {
      scope.$watch(<name of the attribute>, () => {
        // Do something
      });
    }
  };
}
```

I'd like to listen to *bb-civic-registration-number-format* attribute the example below, except I have no idea it's named that way by the programmer reusing my directive:

[image]

I'm trying to create a validation directive which would take an arbitrary expression and use it for validation. A typical example is *ngMin* and *ngMax* except I'd like to implement similar functionality for an arbitrary input type:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="someModel" />
<input type="text" myprefix-max="someModel*0.5" />
```

Comment: Don't you have the attribute in the third argument ?

Comment: Yes, but it's a list of _all_ the attributes on the element. Which one should I read?

Comment: Why don't you make the attribute name a scoped argument that the developer consuming your directive can pass in?

Comment: I'd like to create a directive similar to _ngMin_, which takes a value which it values against the parent scope. The value is then used for validation, which is why I would like to revalidate the element every time the value changes, hence the _$watch_.

Comment: Sounds like an x-y problem.  You are trying to solve your problem one way, which is probably not the correct way, thus creating an unclear question.  Why don't you rephrase your question to illustrate WHAT you are trying to solve?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'attribute that triggered the directive'? Even given your example, I'm still not sure what is special about that attribute or its relation to this directive

Comment: Okay, I've tried to rephrase my question a bit... hopefully it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually get the name of your directive in the compile function, which should give you the ability to look up the value by comparing it to the attribute collection.

```
compile: function (elem, attrs) {
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! :) I'll try that, to be sure!

Comment: Cool let me know how it goes. Interesting question

Comment: It works like a charm! Out of curiosity, is it considered a valid solution to use a variable within the function scope to save the name of the attribute?

Comment: Sure I would almost recommend it. My example was just the least amount of code to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question properly you can use the attribute value and `[]` notation.

```
<element my-directive scope-var="controllerScopePropertyName"></element >
```

JS

```
export function myDirective(): ng.IDirective {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) => {

      // using ES5 syntax
      scope.$watch(function(){
          return scope[attr.scopeVar];
      }, function(newVal,oldVal){
         // do something
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Alternatively just set up isolated scope and bind directly to the controller

Comment: Thank you! But I'd like to use a A-directive, like `<input type="text" my-directive="controllerScopePropertyName">`. In that situation, I don't know the name of `my-directive`, as it depends on the name registered by the programmer (`.directive("name", theDirective)`)

Comment: but that doesn't make sense to have dynamically named attribute and isn't anything angular will handle either. A directive can be set up using attribute or class also...but those names need to be known

Comment: changed to match your `restrict`

Comment: All right. *those names need to be known*: It's what I suspected. Thank you!